# Java Youtube api

Tags: java, api, youtube, youtube-api

I have a question about the java youtube api:

I think the base to every java api program is a YouTubeService instance
So I create one but there are no methods for it(I imported com.google.gdata.client.youtube.YouTubeService) For example I can't do service.getFeed() doesn't work. Or any of the other methods I read in examples and documentation. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `getFeed()` method is inherited from a superclass of `YouTubeService`, so calling it should be no problem. How doesn't it work? Do you see an error when you try to compile?

Comment: I just found out what was going on. I should include all gdata libraries and not only gdata-youtube

Comment: If you managed to resolve the problem, post it as an answer and accept it. :)

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours, then I will

Comment: I've used the YouTube Java API, so I'd love to help you. Sounds like you're doing alright now, but in the future please include an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what was going on. I should include all gdata libraries and not only gdata-youtube